# MYSQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

I have the following code:

```
select c.nome,(p.nome) as ultimo_produto 
from cliente c 
inner join compra cp on (c.cod_cli = cp.fk_cli) 
inner join produto p on(cp.fk_pod=p.cod_pro) 
where  datc >=max(cp.datc)  
group by c.nome;
```

want to get the customer's name and the name of the last product he bought, but the error invalid use of group function

Comment: what is `datc` in `where  datc >=max(cp.datc)`..? i think it might be `c.datc`

Comment: It is not possible to use `max` in the `where` clause. That's the meaning of that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.nome, p.nome as ultimo_produto 
from cliente c 
inner join compra cp on (c.cod_cli = cp.fk_cli) 
inner join produto p on (cp.fk_pod=p.cod_pro) 
inner join 
(
  select cod_pro, max(datc) as mdatc
  from produto
  group by cod_pro
) x on x.cod_pro = p.cod_pro and x.mdatc = p.datc
group by c.nome
```